# Fill cells in Excel 2007 based on content of other cells in row

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel 2007 spreadsheet populated with four columns (V1 V2, V3 V4) that contain values (integers [0-20]) separated by a comma.  Values need not be continuous.
[image: Excel Spreadsheet: example data and output]
I would like to create a new column (e.g. newV) whose cells only contains an integer if it is included in at least two of the previous four columns from that row.  Can this be done with a formula or macro within Excel?  If so what would be a good way to approach this? Thank you.

Comment: Can the same value appear more than once in the same cell?

Comment: It shouldn't. The value should not appear more than once in the cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each value can only appear once in each cell:

```
Function IfAtLeast(rng As Range, num As Integer)
    Const SEP As String = ","
    Dim c As Range, d As Object, arr, i As Long, tmp, k
    Dim rv As String
    rv = ""
    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In rng
        arr = Split(c.Value, SEP)
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            tmp = Trim(arr(i))
            If Not d.exists(tmp) Then d.Add tmp, 0
            d(tmp) = d(tmp) + 1
        Next i
    Next c
    For Each k In d.keys
        If d(k) >= num Then rv = rv & IIf(Len(rv) > 0, ",", "") & k
    Next k
    IfAtLeast = rv
End Function
```

Usage:

```
=IfAtLeast(A2:D2,2)
```

EDIT: if you're having problems trouble-shooting a UDF then it is often easier to debug the issue using a sub

```
Sub Tester()
    debug.print IfAtLeast(Activesheet.Range("A2:D2"), 2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I have copied the above code into my spreadsheet and when I use `=IfAtLeast` and then the range of my cells (e.g. A2:D2) I get a `#Value!` error.  I am unsure on how to error check a function, as opposed to a macro it seems.  Any more suggestions?  Thanks.